# How to store data temporary in spring MVC untill sign up process is not complete?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I working a Spring project.In this project the user sign up either with email or mobile number.After enter email id or mobile number the OTP will be generated and after right OTP user can set their password.This is Sign up So i don't want to save this email or number in database or session.I want to store it temporary until sign up process is not completed.**Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is fine to save the info in session and clear the session info after user creation.

You can also try to store the email or mobile number to cookie (they are relatively small). But anyway you need to store the info somehow.

Comment: Actually I am facing some problem to save data in session because i am using Spring Security.If you have code snippet then please share me.

Comment: http://mrbool.com/how-java-cookies-helps-in-storing-users-information/27795 read this about cookie